# I need to match and expand a tiny url with javascript

Tags: javascript, url, tinyurl

I need to match and expand a tiny url with javascript:

http://t.co/qJEZPFk

No luck with

```
    text.match(/http:\/\/t\.co.*/i)
```

Comment: What's the problem? For the given string, that does match. Are you looking to capture groups?

Answer (score 0):

You can use code like this to capture just the tiny URL code:

```
var url = "http://t.co/qJEZPFk";
var matches = url.match(/http:\/\/t\.co\/([^\/]+)\/?$/);
if (matches && matches.length > 1) {
    var urlCode = matches[1];
}
```

By way of explanation, the regex pattern is this:

- http://t.co/
- Followed by one or more characters that is not a / captured in a group
- Followed by either a slash or the end of string